# Замена дефолтных стрелок у slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Каким образом можно заменить стрелки у `slick'a`? Нашел такой способ:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.head-slider__slider').slick({
    dots: true,
   infinite: true,
   speed: 1000,
   nextArrow: '<img src="../img/angle-left.svg" alt="">',
    prevArrow: '<img src="../img/angle-left.svg" alt="">',
  });
});
```

Но это не сработало. Хочу заменить стандартные иконки на свои `SVG'шные`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вполне рабочий пример. Изменил `arrows` таким же образом:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slick-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '50px',
    prevArrow: "<img src='https://svgshare.com/i/6Ei.svg' class='prev' alt='1'>",
    nextArrow: "<img src='https://svgshare.com/i/6Gf.svg' class='next' alt='2'>",
  });
});
```

```css
.slider-box {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css">
<div class="slider-box">
  <div class="slick-slider">
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Замените внешний вид стрелок с помощью css:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.single-item').slick({
    arrows: true
  });
});
```

```css
.single-item {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" />

<style>
  .slick-prev:before,
  .slick-next:before {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .slick-prev,
  .slick-next {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:5;
  }
  
  .slick-prev,.slick-prev:hover,.slick-prev:focus {
    left: 10px;
    background: url(https://pp.userapi.com/c841622/v841622565/10d5b/-6kAk3WFMKQ.jpg)
  }
  
  .slick-next,.slick-next:hover,.slick-next:focus {
    right: 10px;
    background: url(http://dom2.fans/all_news/0113/img/play-2.png)
  }
</style>

<div class=single-item>
  <div>
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>5</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>6</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```